# How to integrate erlang unit tests in hudson?

Tags: xml, unit-testing, erlang, hudson, eunit

I spent a bit time on this work item ( here , I called it work item ).--- How to integrate the erlang unit test in hudson?

after doing some research, I felt I found the way to resolve this:

1. basically, write the unit test code in erl files. (using eunit )
2. after compiling the project.  generate the unit test result xml using reabr ( here, better to outside of erlang shell) . for example, by command "erl -pa dir -noshell -run module test ......"
3. pass back the xml file , and let hudson reference to the xml file. 
   (I found I block at here .  not clear how to parse the xml file in hudson . do I need to install some other plugin in order to parse the xml generate by eunit  ?)

the exports who view this question, please , please give some suggestions about these steps or show the sensible way to me.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Hudson/Jenkins configuration, under "Post-build actions", check "Publish JUnit test result report" and specify the file names. This plugin, which is installed by default, understands the XML files created by eunit/rebar.

Comment: 1 , write ur unit test code in .erl file  2 , generate the xml file by using the header file of eunit . 3 . parse the xml file with the plugin "Junit"

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins/Hudson's cobertura plugin is usefull too.
See rebar plugin at https://github.com/idubrov/covertool